# use google places API to find "pizza near austin, tx"

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am writing a simple Android app with an `EditText` and a `MapView`. I want to be able to type "pizza near austin, tx", and have the map zoom to pizza places in Austin, TX. I am using the Google API Java Client to send a request to Google Places API, and populate the results as overlays on the map. This is working sort of well, except that the Google Places API requires me to provide a longitude and latitude as part of the [search request](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/#PlaceSearchRequests).

This API seems ideal for finding places near a user's current location. However, if I am in NYC, and I want to see pizza places near Austin, TX, I would first have to parse the search string, map a location-looking part of the string to a longitude and latitude, and then run the query against Google Places API.

I wouldn't mind doing this, if I were sure that there weren't a better way to do it. Is there? It seems like a nut that Google has already cracked. Essentially, what I am looking for is Google Places API which will determine the latitude and longitude from the provided keyword ("pizza near austin, tx").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Places API does not support the use case you are describing. So, yes, the only way to do this **right now** is to perform a geocoding request for "Austin, TX", then supplying the resulting LatLng in your Places Search request, using "pizza" as the  argument. Also, you will have to derive the  argument from the viewport returned by the Geocoding API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcelo. I didn't understand the last sentence "have to derive the argument from the viewport returned by the Geocoding API". Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, its missing a word there. It should read "you will have to derive the **radius** argument from the viewport returned by the Geocoding API."

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can now query this way, read in the documentation:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Look at Text Search Requests
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search